# Android Studio : fetching GPS coordinates of the current marker location in Google Maps

Tags: android, gps

I have the following that needs to be included into an Android application, I'm hoping someone could provide some coding samples to illustrate what exactly I'm attempting to achieve here.

- The Android App has a Google Maps interface on the screen.
- User of the App can browse through the opened Google Map interface and select a particular location.
- I want to fetch the GPS coordinates of this location.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Check the Google apis reference and samples

Comment: I think the latest Android studio 3.3 is not really responding to this code because I'm currently facing some issues with the checkselfpermission